# Firefox Desktop Notifications not showing when multiple tabs are open

Tags: asp.net, firefox, signalr

By `Web Notification` I mean [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification) (The Notification interface of the Notifications API is used to configure and display desktop notifications to the user).

I have Asp.Net MVC web app and I have a button in my page which supposed to push a notification to clients.
I also used `signalr` to push message and call notification function.

my `layout.cshtml` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn" type="button">click</button>
    @RenderBody()
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            var myHub = $.connection.chatHub;
            myHub.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (title, message) {
                var options = {
                    body: message,
                    tag: 'aaa'
                }

                // check permissions if already granted
                if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
                    var notification = new Notification(title, options);
                } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
                    // request permission
                    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                        // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
                        if (permission === "granted") {
                            var notification = new Notification(title, options);
                        }
                    });
                }

                console.log('the hub method called sucessfully');
            }
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#btn').on('click', function () {
                    myHub.server.send('foo', 'bar');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, the push notifications stops working/showing in firefox when I have multiple pages of my app open. (it works when single tab is open).
this bug only happens in firefox and works well in chrome and IE.


[image: animated gif]

**update 1:**
I think its not signalr problem since the hub method is invoked.

this line is called on all tabs:
`console.log('the hub method called sucessfully');`
and signalr logging says that:

```
SignalR: Invoking myhub.Send jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js
SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'addNewMessageToPage' on hub 'MyHub'. jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js
foo bar
SignalR: Invoked myhub.Send jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a Firefox bug.

The way worked for me was call the Notification in a different time. This is not a complete fix but is working well.

```
var randomTime = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1) * 50;

            setTimeout(function () {
                newNotification = new Notification(Title, NotificationContent);
            }, randomTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34315275/1097429)

And I suggest to use IWC-SignalR from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34320865/1097429)

Comment: I tried you answer. sadly it doesn't fixed my problem. I made an update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to Web Socket. You have to enable your websocket first.

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
```

then you can user socket start function to detect your connections.

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'webSockets' }).done(function () { .. });
```